# Source Control folder organisation for distributed team

Tags: svn, version-control

Our team is distributed across two geographic locations.
We share and use similar scripts for the automation of different tests we perform.
We have recently decided to use source control to manage the different scripts that are being used. So far whatever scripts we generated was shared across to the other location, they would make minor local modification appropriate to their needs and use it. 
That is we would be using the same version of the script with few minor modification specific to our local setup.
How best to organise this in a source control. We are planning to use Subversion with the repository duplicated across the two location.

One solution I was thinking was making two folders one for each location. Thus any scripts they upload, we will copy to our own directory and make local modification. Any other suggestions?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a single repository to hold the scripts.  Each modification (by local or remote team) would get versioned. Changes can be rolled back.  You will have revision history and so on.  Multiple folders defeat the purpose of having a version control system.  Of course, you can have subfolders for logical separation of scripts.

If network performance is an issue, you may want to look at distributed version control systems like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

Comment: We would be using the same version of the script with some minor modification specific to the location. Will not using different revision in each location create confusion when updating them? I would very much like to use Git but is not supported by the our company yet :( ...

Comment: @Manoj.  You should try to parametrize or move out location-specific entries in the script.  These entries can be saved locally and not checked into the repository.

Answer (score 1):

That is what a **branch per site** looks like.
Each site has complete ownership on their branch, and you import/merge changes made by one site in your site branch.

Except that, with a Centralized VCS, it is better to access the SVN repo remotely (for one of the sites), in order to avoid any history discrepancies between two manual clones.

As [Raghuram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254643/raghuram), Git or Mercurial are a better fit for that scenario.

Comment: Branch per site - that means we will start from a single trunk, create one branch for each site and continue modifying it. We can pull required updates and modification from the other branch. The branch will never be merged to the trunk? Is this right?

Comment: @Manoj: yes, if you don't need those modification on trunk, you won't ever merge them back. But if some evolutions are made on remote site, you can review those and merge them in your own branch.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with SVN but have worked extensively with other many vcs systems and ...

I agree a priority should be "You should try to parametrize or move out location-specific entries", BUT the first priority to get all your scripts under source control in a common repository. In fact, your process documentation should also be under source control.

I previously joined a CM team which failed to use a CM tools for their own scripts. Sure enough, every so often we would discover a problem which not all members would be using the same scripts for the same tasks. Putting the scripts and documents in the repository makes it convenient and easy to have everyone using the same tools and stay up to date.

To universalize your scripts, etc., create a folder tree for the scripts with common/site A/site B/ structure. Place all scripts for the respective sites under the directory. Identical scripts are then migrated to "common" and deleted from the others and check everything in. The ultimate objective is to move all scripts to a common code base. A common de-localization framework or template for achieving this will speed up the process. You'll find once the first few are done, the rest will follow very quickly. Having the separate directories allows you to easily diff the localizations and eliminate them.

You do not want to be in a situation where users must constantly merge (ugh!) and overwrite localization data for their locale or worse do it manually after check-out. Optimally, when updating any scripts, they should be done with the de-localizing objective in mind, so only accept updates to common unless there are extenuating circumstances; also force the updater to update both A and B branches when doing one side. You'll find people get tired of doing things twice (and for someone else's benefit) and will readily start de-localizing scripts.